# Installing xml2 on AWS EC2 Ubuntu server in R, libcurl isn't an R capability

Tags: amazon-ec2, libcurl, xml2

I have an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance with R installed, and I am attempting to install xml2.

install.packages("xml2")

results in:

Warning message:
package ‘xml2’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

and

devtools::install_github("hadley/xml2")

results in:

Downloading GitHub repo hadley/xml2@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/xml2/zipball/master
Installing xml2
Error in if (capabilities("libcurl")) { : argument is of length zero

I have installed libcurl4-openssl-dev on my server already, but when I ask R for

capabilities()

I get:

jpeg      png     tiff    tcltk      X11     aqua http/ftp  sockets 
    TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE 
  libxml     fifo   cledit    iconv      NLS  profmem    cairo 
    TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE

With no libcurl.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you ever found an answer for this but this is the reason: "(for R version 3.0.2)"

Get the latest package for your system and this should be fine.

```
any(names(capabilities("libcurl")))
```

will report either true or false on success.